# How to have a custom icon for my application.exe/executable QT, i used Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt

I wanted to have a custom icon for my application.exe executable , i have also tried referring this documentation `https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/appicon.html`, but i didn't use QT-Creator to create my project,so i don't have the .pro file to make any changes, i have used Visual Studio 2019 to work on my project and complete it.

How can i set a custom icon when i used Visual studio 2019 ?

Answer (score 1):

For **Qt 5**, this process is automated by qmake. Just add the following to the project file:

```
win32:RC_ICONS += your_icon.ico
```

Comment: That's my question , where do i find the .pro file, i didn't use Qt creator, i used visual studio.

Comment: in one of the Qt forums i saw this `VS doesn't use .PRO file, so you can't just edit it.

However, if you install the Qt plugin, you can create .pro file from your .vcproj, edit that file and then convert it back to a vcproj. Kind of long winded approach though and may lose other configuration settings. Why not edit the vcproj file instead?`     so can i do `win32:RC_ICONS += your_icon.ico` in my VCPROJ instead ?